kubernetes dashboard create token fails
Docker Desktop For Windows on WSL2
I'm following the k8s blog here :
https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/05/21/wsl-docker-kubernetes-on-the-windows-desktop/
I'm able to create the kubernetes dashboard
x@y:~$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0-rc6/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
namespace/kubernetes-dashboard created
serviceaccount/kubernetes-dashboard created
service/kubernetes-dashboard created
secret/kubernetes-dashboard-certs created
secret/kubernetes-dashboard-csrf created
secret/kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder created
configmap/kubernetes-dashboard-settings created
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard created
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard created
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard created
Warning: spec.template.spec.nodeSelector[beta.kubernetes.io/os]: deprecated since v1.14; use "kubernetes.io/os" instead
deployment.apps/kubernetes-dashboard created
service/dashboard-metrics-scraper created
Warning: spec.template.metadata.annotations[seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/pod]: non-functional in v1.27+; use the "seccompProfile" field instead
deployment.apps/dashboard-metrics-scraper created

x@y:~$ kubectl get all -n kubernetes-dashboard
NAME                                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/dashboard-metrics-scraper-759b7c86cc-kgc9z   1/1     Running   0          28s
pod/kubernetes-dashboard-b5978f84b-ctqfz         1/1     Running   0          28s

NAME                                TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
service/dashboard-metrics-scraper   ClusterIP   10.96.108.183   <none>        8000/TCP   28s
service/kubernetes-dashboard        ClusterIP   10.96.154.234   <none>        443/TCP    29s

NAME                                        READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/dashboard-metrics-scraper   1/1     1            1           28s
deployment.apps/kubernetes-dashboard        1/1     1            1           28s

NAME                                                   DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/dashboard-metrics-scraper-759b7c86cc   1         1         1       28s
replicaset.apps/kubernetes-dashboard-b5978f84b         1         1         1       28s

and start a proxy
x@y:~$ kubectl proxy
Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8001

but creating a token fails
x@y:/mnt/c/Users/x$ kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: admin-user
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
EOF
serviceaccount/admin-user created

x@y:/mnt/c/Users/x$ kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: admin-user
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: admin-user
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
EOF
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/admin-user created

x@y:/mnt/c/Users/x$ kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard describe secret $(kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard get secret | grep admin-user | awk '{print $1}')
Name:         kubernetes-dashboard-certs
Namespace:    kubernetes-dashboard
Labels:       k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  Opaque

Data
====


Name:         kubernetes-dashboard-csrf
Namespace:    kubernetes-dashboard
Labels:       k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  Opaque

Data
====
csrf:  256 bytes


Name:         kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder
Namespace:    kubernetes-dashboard
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  Opaque

Data
====
priv:  1679 bytes
pub:   459 bytes


To create token you have to execute:
kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard create token admin-user

